# What is the better approach to convert primitive data type into String

Tags: java

I can convert an integer into string using

```
String s = "" + 4; // correct, but poor style
or
String u = Integer.toString(4); // this is good
```

I can convert a double into string using

```
String s = "" + 4.5; // correct, but poor style
or
String u = Double.toString(4.5); // this is good
```

I can use `String s = "" + data`approach to convert either an int or double into String. While If I wants to use the other approach using `toString()` I have to use the Wrapper class of each data type. Then why in [**some books**](http://ww0.java3.datastructures.net/contents/supplement2.pdf)  it is mentioned that the first approach is poor one while the second one is the better. **Which one is the better approach and why?**

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I would use

```
String.valueOf(...)
```

You can use the same code for all types, but without the hideous and pointless string concatenation.

Note that it also says exactly what you want - the string value corresponding to the given primitive value. Compare that with the `"" + x` approach, where you're applying string concatenation even though you have no intention of concatenating anything, and the empty string is irrelevant to you. (It's probably more expensive, but it's the readability hit that I mind more than performance.)

Answer (score 31):

How about `String.valueOf()`? It's <s>overridden</s> overloaded for all primitive types and delegates to `toString()` for reference types.

Comment: Overloaded, not overridden :)

Comment: Is it better than using "" + 4.5  if yes how?

Comment: @Deepakkk: Yes, it's better, because (as everyone else has already said) it makes the code say what it does rather than having the intended operation as a side effect.

Answer (score 10):

```
String s = "" + 4;
```

Is compiled to this code:

```
StringBuffer _$_helper = new StringBuffer("");
_$_helper.append(Integer.toString(4));
String s = _$_helper.toString();
```

Obviously that is pretty wastefull.
Keep in mind that behind the scene the compiler is always using StringBuffers if you use + in asociation with String's

Comment: **Actually* `String s = "" + 4;` compiles to the *exact* same bytecode as `String s = "4";`. If `4` were replaced with a non-compile time constant expression (for example with `i` defined as `int i = 4;`), then it would be closer to your code, but my compiler (Java 6u26) uses `append(int)` of `StringBuilder`  instead of calling `Integer.toString()`.

Comment: I did not get that, is it now using StringBuilder.append or is it doing a String s = "4"? The later one is basically equivalen to String s = new String ("4"); Anyway, you are right about the compile time constant, I should have thought about it ;D

Comment: the way you posted it, it's equivalent to just `"4"`. *If* your replace `4` with a variable with the value `4`, *then* it will use `StringBuilder.append()`.

Comment: True, I forgot that the const ("4") will be in the constant pool of the class. So there is no "new String" needed.

Answer (score 9):

There's a third one - `String.valueOf(..)` (which calls `Wrapper.toString(..)`

Actually the compiler adds `Wrapper.toString(..)` in these places, so it's the same in terms of bytecode. But `""+x` is uglier.

Answer (score 6):

The string-concatenation way creates an extra object (that then gets GCed), that is one reason why it's considered "poorer". Plus it is trickier and less readable, which as Jon Skeet points out is usually a bigger consideration.

Comment: That's *one* reason, but to my mind it's less important than the readability reason - the code doesn't state what it's trying to achieve.

Comment: @little bunny foo foo: No, there's no reason to use autoboxing at all here.

Comment: @Jon, Oh...I thought that's what the `.valueOf(...)` method did. Maybe I'm using the wrong term?

Comment: @little bunny foo foo: I suspect so. When you call `String.valueOf(int)` or `Integer.toString(int)` there's no reason to suppose that will create an instance of `Integer`.

Comment: string concatenation to make a String is an idiom in Java and should not be considered bad style

Comment: @Adam: I'm not terribly worked up about this specific case. but just because something is common enough to be an idiom doesn't make it above criticism. Javascript and Ruby have some horrible things that have graduated to the level of idioms.

Comment: @Nathan - that's true, but it does defeat the readability argument. I believe that every Java programmer reads that and understands it.

Answer (score 4):

I would also use `String.valueOf()` method, which, in effect, uses the primitive type's Wrapper object and calls the `toString()` method for you:

Example, in the `String` class:

```
public static String valueOf(int i) {
        return Integer.toString(i, 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Appending a double quote is a bad way of doing it especially for readability.  I would consider using some of the Apache util classes for conversion or writing your own utility methods for doing this type of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better that you're aware of the type of argument you are trying to convert to string and also make compiler aware of the type. That simplifies the operation as well as the cycles. When you follow the append method, you are leaving the type decision to the compiler and also increasing the code lines for the compiler to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer really depends on what you're trying to convert, and for what purpose, but in general, I'm not a big fan of doing naked conversions, because in most instances, conversions to a string are for logging, or other human readability purposes.

```
MessageFormat.format("The value of XYZ object is {0}", object);
```

This gives good readability, fine grained control over the formatting of the output, and importantly, it can be internationalized by replacing the string with a message bundle reference.

Need I mention this also avoids the possible NPE problem of calling object.toString()?

Comment: +1: The local string representation of even a positive integer is not the same everywhere: 1000 or 1,000 or 1.000? In simple debugging code these differences are not important, but it matters for "proper" UI text.